# Include Foreign key records in Entity Framework

Tags: sql, .net, entity-framework

First, allow me to apologize, I am VERY new to EF and have inherited a bunch of code I barely understand.  So this might not be the best phrased question... but here it goes.

I'm using Dotnet Core with EF and have the following setup for each class.

NoteTable:

```
public int NoteId { get; set;}
public string Description { get; set; } 
public List<NoteDetails> NoteDetails {get; set; }
```

NoteDetails

```
public string Description { get; set; }
public int NoteDetailId { get; set; }
public int NoteId { get; set; }
public MetaDataOptions Frequency { get; set; }
public int? FrequencyId { get; set; }
public MetaDataOptions Width { get; set; }
public int? WidthId { get; set; }
public MetaDataOptions Length { get; set; }
public int? LengthId { get; set; }
```

MetaDataOptions:

```
public int MetaDataId { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public int? DisplayOrder { get; set; }
public bool IsActive { get; set; }
```

Where I am looking at the code, the data for NoteDetailsTable is filled out and FrequencyId, WeightId and LengthID are all filled out with their perspective IDs reference the MetaDataOptions table.

The code then does some EF Magic:

```
_clinicalSummaryDbContext.NoteDetails.Select(a => a.Frequency).Load();
_clinicalSummaryDbContext.NoteDetails.Select(a => a.Width).Load();
_clinicalSummaryDbContext.NoteDetails.Select(a => a.Height).Load();
```

And the response object looks like:

```html
{
   "NoteID":1,
   "Description":"First Note",
   "NoteDetails":[
      {
         "NoteId":1,
         "FrequencyId":1,
         "Frequency":{
            "RefTableId":1,
            "description":"Frequency Desciption"
         },
         "WidthId":2,
         "Width":{
            "RefTableId":2,
            "description":"Width Description"
         },
         "HeightID":3,
         "Height":{
            "RefTableId":3,
            "description":"Height Description"
         }
      }
   ]
 }
```

This is Exactly what I want.  The issue however, is our Performance team noticed that the 3 Load events (.Select(a => a.Frequency).Load();...) is pulling down the entire notedetails table.  Not just the records associated with the note.  When I put a profiler on SQL, I can see it run the following statement, once for each reference

```html
SELECT [w].[WoundDetailId] ...
FROM [NoteDetail] AS [w]
LEFT JOIN [MetaDataOptions] AS [w.Frequency] ON [w].[FrequencyId] = [w.Frequency].[MetaDataOptionId]
```

My question is, can I convert that load statement so that it ONLY loads the single MetaDataOptions record for each of the references and attaches it to the response object the same way as above.

I hope I explained this well enough.  Happy to provide any additional information that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, those `Load` statements would trigger reading all grandchildren into memory. Once the DB Context has them tracked, when you load a Note/NoteDetail, it will magically populate those related entities.  It's very wasteful from a performance and resource utilization POV and something easily overlooked during development with a limited data set, which will get significantly worse over time in production as the data set grows.

It sounds like what they want is to eager load the details with the Note.  For example, If I have:

```
var note = _clinicalSummaryDbContext.Notes
    .Include(n => n.NoteDetails)
    .Single(n => n.NoteId == noteId);
```

This would load a single note with it's details, but not the Frequency/Width/Height for each of those details.

To get those included with EF Core:

```
var note = _clinicalSummaryDbContext.Notes
    .Include(n => n.NoteDetails).ThenInclude(nd => nd.Frequency)
    .Include(n => n.NoteDetails).ThenInclude(nd => nd.Width)
    .Include(n => n.NoteDetails).ThenInclude(nd => nd.Height)
    .Single(n => n.NoteId == noteId);
```

This looks a bit funky with re-including the NoteDetails, but necessary for multiple grandchild references, and frankly it's not that intuitive, but EF will chew that down to loading the details, with their respective Frequency, Width, and Height in a single query.

Alternatively, when loading data that will be sent to a view or API client, it's generally better to *not* send Entities, but rather DTOs/ViewModels which are projected from the related entities. Sending entities often involves sending more data to a client than the client needs, and reveals too much about your entire domain. (Sending entities back to the server is a serious data integrity risk)

For example you could have a NoteDTO with a NoteDetailDTO where the relevant Freqency/Width/Height fields are flattened into the NoteDetailDTO, or represented by DTOs themselves. The DTOs can be populated using a `.Select` statement without the need for any `.Include` or `.ThenInclude`, or you can utilize Automapper and its `.ProjectTo` to translate EF entities into DTOs. `ProjectTo` works with EF `IQueryable` to generate SQL to populate the relevant fields.

When mapping is set up to translate Note entity structures to a NoteDTO entity structure, you end up with something like:

```
var noteDTO = _clinicalSummaryDbContext.Notes
    .Where(n => n.NoteId == noteId)
    .ProjectTo<NoteDTO>(configuration)
    .Single();
```

Where `configuration` points to the Automapper configuration for translating the entity structure to DTO structure.

Edit: Based on the information from the comment, assuming the Note and NoteDetail were already loaded, another option would be to replace the `.Load()` calls with something like this:

```
// Find missing references for Frequencies, widths, and height metadata.
var frequencyIds = note.NoteDetails
    .Where(x => x.FrequencyId.HasValue && x.Frequency == null)
    .Select(x => x.FrequencyId)
    .ToList();
var widthIds = note.NoteDetails
    .Where(x => x.WidthId.HasValue && x.Width == null)
    .Select(x => x.WidthId)
    .ToList();
var heightIds = note.NoteDetails
    .Where(x => x.HeightId.HasValue && x.Height == null)
    .Select(x => x.HeightId)
    .ToList();
var missingMetadataOptionIds = frequencyIds.Concat(widthIds).Concat(heightIds);

var missingMetadata = _clinicalSummaryDbContext.MetadataOptions
    .Where(x => missingMetadataOptionIds.Contains(x.MetadataOptionId))
    .ToList();

foreach(var noteDetail in note.NoteDetails)
{
   if(noteDetail.Frequency == null)
       noteDetail.Frequency = missingMetadata.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MetadataOptionId == noteDetail.FrequencyId);
   if(noteDetail.Width == null)
       noteDetail.Width = missingMetadata.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MetadataOptionId == noteDetail.WidthId);
   if(noteDetail.Height == null)
       noteDetail.Height = missingMetadata.SingleOrDefault(x => x.MetadataOptionId == noteDetail.HeightId);
}
```

This assumes these `Load` calls were happening after the Note/NoteDetails were loaded. If the load calls were happening before the Note was loaded then the likely best available solution would be to add the eager load `Include`/`ThenInclude` statements.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful in general Thank You!

Unfortunately,  I'm not sure it helps with my currently situation.  The code I'm asked to fix already has a modified version of Notes and noteDetails loaded by the time it gets to the function I'm trying to fix.  So I wouldn't be able to make a new EF call to get notes with notedetails and the metadataoptions included.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to cover a possible solution to replace the `Load` calls if those were happening after the Note/NoteDetails were loaded. Basically get the IDs of the missing entities and load just those Metadata then go through and set the missing references. This also assumes that the Note/NoteDetails are *not* tracked entities which I'm guessing they aren't or they would have Lazy-loaded.